# SQL Server Max Function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
a.name, a.address, n.date, n.note
FROM a
LEFT JOIN n ON a.id = n.id
```

The `a.id` has a one to many relationship with `n.id`, so that many notes can be assocaited with one name.

How do I return just the latest note for each name instead of all the notes?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT t.name, t.address, t.date, t.note
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.name, a.address, n.date, n.note,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.name ORDER BY n.date DESC) rn
    FROM a
    LEFT JOIN n ON a.id = n.id
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

alternative you can use a correlated subquery too get the max date, something like this

```
SELECT
    a.name, a.address, n.date, n.note
FROM a
LEFT JOIN n ON a.id = n.id
WHERE n.date = (SELECT MAX(nn.date) 
                FROM n AS nn 
                WHERE a.id = nn.id)
```

Comment: Good answer, but possibly overkill?

Comment: @SelectDistinct do you have a simpler way to accomplish the desired result? If so, why not post an answer, or elaborate on why you think this is overkill.

Comment: Hi T I,
Thanks for your response.
The script is actually a simplified version of a larger, more complex query involving many tables and joins. Is there an alternative to having the entire query in a sub query of the From clause as this means any change to a field, join etc. needs to be done twice? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks T I, the alternative solution is perfect. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @aaron-bertrand I was thinking this could be accomplished by using a join and the max function, t-i has also identified this and updated his answer which I think was the one OP has gone with

Comment: Hi again. A name may not necessarily have a corresponding note; how do I adapt the query to take this into account? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `OR n.date IS NULL` to the main query's `WHERE` clause

Comment: @SelectDistinct while that may look simpler I'd compare the plans. SQL might be very smart about optimizing them the same way, but it might not.

Comment: Hi Select Distinct. Unfortunately, I don't have sufficient permissions in the database to look at the execution plan. Is there a more efficient way of writing the query? Thanks.

Comment: @user2493043 you can implement a query but you can't check that its execution plan makes sense? That seems like something you should correct.