# Selecting only rows with the latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query to get the contact names with the latest dates. 
I have a table that has more than one result for each contact but with different dates and i am trying to get the latest result for that contact.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362338/sql-server-max-function/18362443?noredirect=1#comment26986890_18362443

Answer (score 5):

Use the [ranking function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY Date DESC`:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY contactId
                       ORDER BY date DESC) AS RN
   FROM tablename
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

This will give you only the row with the latest date for each contact.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'NEXT'
    FROM contacts c2
    WHERE c1.fk_parent = c2.fk_parent
    AND c2.date > c1.date)
```

For next time, add your tables (with field and relations).

My sample is very generic because I don't know your structure

fk_parent, I assume, is a field representing a foreign key, where, two different contacts are linked (for example that field can be a customer field)

Answer (score 0):

Also, something like...

```
select id, contactname from contacts c1
where contactdate = (select max(contactdate) from contacts c2 where c2.id=c1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will create a temp table with the max date per contact.  joining this temp table to you base table will get you the results your looking for.

```
     create table #latestContact (lastdate datetime ,contactid int);
     insert into #latestContact (lastdate, contactid)
     select max(createdate)
     ,contactid 
     from ContactTable
     group by contactid;

     select * 
     from contactTable c
     join #latestContact l
     on l.lastdate = c.createdate
     and l.contactid = c.contactid;
```

I'm note sure what your table structure looks like but I assume your contact table has a primary key (contacted) and also uses a create date time field (createdate).

This may be better than the cte ranking example above because it will not select unwanted rows and then filter them out of your final result set. However, I haven't looked at a query plan or the stats on either solution - this would be a good way to see what works best.

Hope this helps.